# Interactive bend image

Tags: css, graphics, html5-canvas

I'd like to transform image in web browser this way

[image] -> 
[image]

more precisely, it should be 3D effect (like wrap the image around can). I'm considering these options:

- CSS3 transform (is it possible with matrix3d somehow?)
- HTML5 canvas (I don't have any experience here yet)
- applet or flash (this would be least preffered)

I hope there is some simple smart way how to achieve this, but some 3rd party heavy library could also do the job. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why not send it for image-processing at the back-end? I haven't used anything related to image-processing but I think there will be some options to achieve what you want. Upload the image, send it to the script get response as `data` URL or something.

Comment: It should be interactive, I'd like to turn the can on which the image would be placed.

Comment: The closest idea that I know of http://www.romancortes.com/blog/pure-css-coke-can/

Comment: Try looking at the code on [Ezimba](http://www.ezimba.com/index-ln.html#home). They have a bend feature under the warp category.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can slice your image into 1 pixel slices and then offset those slices to visually wrap around your cup:

**Left:** Image wrapped around top of cup, **Right:** Image wrapped around center of cup.

[image][image]

**Here's example code and a Demo:**

```js
var faceCanvas=document.getElementById('face');
var faceCtx=faceCanvas.getContext('2d');

var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw,ch;


$myslider=$('#myslider');
$myslider.val(50);

var PI=Math.PI;
var cupTop=78;
var cupBottom=295;
var dxx=19;
var dyy=34;
var l={x0:41,y0:cupTop,x1:74,y1:cupBottom};
var r={x0:249,y0:cupTop,x1:218,y1:cupBottom};
var t={
  x0:l.x0,
  y0:l.y0,
  x1:l.x0+dxx,
  y1:r.y0+dyy,
  x2:r.x0-dxx,
  y2:r.y0+dyy,
  x3:r.x0,
  y3:r.y0
};
var b={
  x0:l.x1,
  y0:l.y1,
  x1:l.x1+dxx,
  y1:r.y1+dyy,
  x2:r.x1-dxx,
  y2:r.y1+dyy,
  x3:r.x1,
  y3:r.y1
};
var topOffset=40;

var imgCount=2;
var cup=new Image();
cup.crossOrigin='anonymous';
cup.onload=start;
var pic=new Image();
pic.crossOrigin='anonymous';
pic.onload=start;
cup.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/PaperCup.png";
//pic.src='https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/avatars1.jpg';
pic.src='https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/google.png'
function start(){
  if(--imgCount>0){return;}

  cw=canvas.width=faceCanvas.width=cup.width;
  ch=canvas.height=faceCanvas.height=cup.height;

  draw();

  face();

  $myslider.change(function(){
    var value=parseInt($(this).val())/100;
    topOffset=(l.y1-l.y0-pic.height)*value;
    draw();
    face();
  });

}


function face(){

  //
  var lm=(l.y1-l.y0)/(l.x1-l.x0);
  var lb=l.y1-(lm*l.x1);
  //
  var rm=(r.y1-r.y0)/(r.x1-r.x0);
  var rb=r.y1-(rm*r.x1);

  faceCtx.clearRect(0,0,faceCanvas.width,faceCanvas.height);

  for(var y=0;y<pic.height;y++){

    var yy=cupTop+topOffset+y;
    var leftX=(yy-lb)/lm;
    var rightX=(yy-rb)/rm;
    var width=rightX-leftX;

    faceCtx.drawImage(
      pic,
      0,y,pic.width,1,
      leftX,yy,width,1
    );  

  }

  var yy=cupTop+topOffset;
  var p0={x:(yy-lb)/lm,y:cupTop+topOffset};
  var p3={x:(yy-rb)/rm,y:cupTop+topOffset};
  var p1={x:p0.x+dxx,y:p0.y+dyy};
  var p2={x:p3.x-dxx,y:p3.y+dyy};
  var points=calcPointsOnBezier(p0,p1,p2,p3);

  ctx.save();
  setClip();
  ctx.clip();

  for(var x in points){
    var y=points[x];
    ctx.drawImage(faceCanvas,  x,0,1,ch,  x,y-yy,1,ch );
    ctx.drawImage(faceCanvas,  x,0,1,ch,  x,y-yy,1,ch );
  } 
  ctx.restore();
}

function setClip(){
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(t.x0,t.y0)
  ctx.bezierCurveTo(t.x1,t.y1,t.x2,t.y2,t.x3,t.y3);
  ctx.lineTo(r.x1,r.y1);
  ctx.bezierCurveTo(b.x2,b.y2,b.x1,b.y1,b.x0,b.y0);
  ctx.lineTo(t.x0,t.y0);
}

function calcPointsOnBezier(p0,p1,p2,p3){
  var points={};
  for(var x=parseInt(p0.x);x<parseInt(p3.x+1);x++){
    points[x]=p0.y;
  }
  for(var i=0;i<1000;i++){
    var t=i/1000;
    var pt=getCubicBezierXYatT(p0,p1,p2,p3,t);
    points[parseInt(pt.x)]=parseInt(pt.y);
  }
  return(points);
}

function draw(){
  ctx.strokeStyle='gold';
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
  ctx.drawImage(cup,0,0);
}

function getCubicBezierXYatT(startPt,controlPt1,controlPt2,endPt,T){
  var x=CubicN(T,startPt.x,controlPt1.x,controlPt2.x,endPt.x);
  var y=CubicN(T,startPt.y,controlPt1.y,controlPt2.y,endPt.y);
  return({x:x,y:y});
}

// cubic helper formula at T distance
function CubicN(T, a,b,c,d) {
  var t2 = T * T;
  var t3 = t2 * T;
  return a + (-a * 3 + T * (3 * a - a * T)) * T
  + (3 * b + T * (-6 * b + b * 3 * T)) * T
  + (c * 3 - c * 3 * T) * t2
  + d * t3;
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
Vertical Position:<input id=myslider type=range min=0 max=100 value=50><br>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
<canvas id="face" width=300 height=300 hidden></canvas>
```

Comment: It's partial code that I pulled from an archived project of mine. ;-)